# Error fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError and other relationship and back_population problems (not load related records)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel, tortoise-orm

#### Summary of my most important problem:

Basically, I want to get my response validated by my schema from SQLModel, but I have the error and I don't have idea what field/part cause it, there is not an explanation.

#### My minimum example code:

```
# I had to divide in two files because of an error related to "clients" table already in metadata.
# It is a minimal, because the models are more complex and I think I would get more errors related to TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class because of the order of the related tables.

# test.py 
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, Relationship, Column, create_engine, Session, select
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, func
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Any, Dict, Optional


###############################################
# MODELS:
# Related models:
class Jobs(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner_id: int = Field(nullable=False, foreign_key="usermodel.id")

    expected_pay_date: date
    pay_date: Optional[date]
    start_date: date
    nfe_date: Optional[date]
    value: float
    description: str
    costs: float = Field(default=0)
    is_nfe_issued: bool = Field(default=False)
    estimated_hours: Optional[float]
    nfe_url: str = Field(max_length=250)
    boleto_url: str = Field(max_length=250)
    pix_url: str = Field(max_length=250)
    report_url: str = Field(max_length=250)
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)

    pay_account_id: int = Field(foreign_key="paymentaccount.id")
    pay_type_id: int = Field(foreign_key="paymenttypes.id")
    status_id: int = Field(foreign_key="jobstatus.id")
    client_id: int = Field(foreign_key="clients.id")

    # types: List["JobTypes"] = Relationship(back_populates="jobs",
    #                                        link_model=JobJobTypesLink)  # Not really appear in the table
    client: "Clients" = Relationship(back_populates="jobs")  # Not really appear in the table

    # pay_type: "PaymentTypes" = Relationship(back_populates="jobs")
    # pay_account: "PaymentAccount" = Relationship(back_populates="jobs")

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        read_with_orm_mode = True


class ClientNotes(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner_id: int = Field(nullable=False, foreign_key="usermodel.id")

    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at: Optional[datetime] = Field(sa_column=Column(DateTime(), onupdate=func.now()))
    note: str

    client_id: int = Field(foreign_key="clients.id")
    client: "Clients" = Relationship(back_populates="notes")


class ClientObjective(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: str = Field(unique=True, nullable=False, max_length=60)
    clients: List["Clients"] = Relationship(back_populates="objective")


class ClientTypes(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: str = Field(unique=True, nullable=False, max_length=60)
    clients: List["Clients"] = Relationship(back_populates="client_type")


class ClientsBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(unique=True, nullable=False, max_length=60)
    description: Optional[str] = None
    owner_id: int = Field(nullable=False, foreign_key="usermodel.id")

    status: bool = Field(default=True)
    cnpj: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=19)
    email: str = Field(max_length=60, nullable=False)
    emails_finance: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=180)
    emails_reports: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=180)
    hubspot_url: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=120)
    proposal_url: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=120)
    industry: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=60)
    discount_period: Optional[int] = None
    discount_perc: Optional[int] = None

    client_type_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="clienttypes.id")
    objective_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="clientobjective.id")


class Clients(ClientsBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)

    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at: Optional[datetime] = Field(sa_column=Column(DateTime(), onupdate=func.now()))

    jobs: List["Jobs"] = Relationship(back_populates="client", sa_relationship_kwargs={
        "lazy": 'joined'
    })  # Not really appear in the table
    notes: List["ClientNotes"] = Relationship(back_populates="client", sa_relationship_kwargs={
        "lazy": 'joined'
    })  # Not really appear in the table
    objective: "ClientObjective" = Relationship(back_populates="clients", sa_relationship_kwargs={
        "lazy": 'joined'
    })  # Not really appear in the table
    client_type: "ClientTypes" = Relationship(back_populates="clients", sa_relationship_kwargs={
        "lazy": 'joined'
    })  # Not really appear in the table

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        read_with_orm_mode = True


class ClientsRead(ClientsBase):
    id: int
    created_at: Optional[datetime] = None
    updated_at: Optional[datetime] = None

    jobs: Optional[List["Jobs"]] = []
    notes: Optional[List["ClientNotes"]] = []
    objective: Optional["ClientObjective"] = None
    client_type: Optional["ClientTypes"] = None


class ClientsCreate(ClientsBase):
    pass


# DB CONFIG
connect_args = {"check_same_thread": False}
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.sqlite3", echo=True, connect_args=connect_args)
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session
```

```
####################################
# main.py

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Depends, Query, Response
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from typing import List, Any, Dict, Optional
from sqlmodel import Session, select
from test import Clients, ClientsRead, get_session
from datetime import date
###############################################
# FAST API

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/clients",
    tags=["Clients"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not Found"}},
)


# Get many items
@router.get("/", response_model=List[ClientsRead])
async def read_clients(
        *,
        response: Response,
        session: Session = Depends(get_session),
        _start: Optional[int] = 0, _end: Optional[int] = 0,
        _order: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="ASC or DESC (Ascending or Descending"),
        _sort: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="The field used to order"),
        # user: User = Depends(current_active_user),
        id: Optional[List[int]] = Query(
            None, description="List of ids of the clients"),
        type_of_client: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="The type of recurrence: Monthly, Freelance"),
        email: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="Main email address of the client"),
        cnpj: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="CNPJ of the client"),
        name: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="Name of the client"),
        objective: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="The main objective of the client: Leads, Sales, Others..."),
        creation_date_start: Optional[date] = Query(
            None, description="Initial interval of creation date, format: YYY-MM-DD"),
        creation_date_end: Optional[date] = Query(
            None, description="End interval of creation date, format: YYY-MM-DD"),
        industry_type: Optional[str] = Query(
            None, description="The main industry of the client"),
        status: Optional[bool] = Query(
            None, description="Is the client active or inactive?"),
):
    # NEED TO ADAPT FROM TORTOISE ORM TO SQLMODEL (How? It accepts strings for fields?)
    filters: Dict[Any, Any] = {"id__in": id,
                               "client_type__name__icontains": type_of_client,
                               "email__icontains": email,
                               "cnpj__icontains": cnpj,
                               "name__icontains": name,
                               "objective__name__icontains": objective,
                               "created_at__gte": creation_date_start,
                               "created_at__lte": creation_date_end,
                               "industry__icontains": industry_type,
                               "status": status}
    used_filters = {key: value for key, value in filters.items() if value is not None}

    order_dict: Dict[str] = {"ASC": "", "DESC": "-"}
    if _order and _sort:
        order_str: str = f"{order_dict.get(_order)}{_sort}".lower()
    else:
        order_str: str = "id"

    if _end:
        client_list = session.exec(select(Clients).offset(_start).limit(_end - _start).order_by(order_str)).all()
        print(client_list)
    else:
        client_list = session.exec(select(Clients).offset(_start)
                                   .order_by(order_str)
                                   # .where(Clients.owner_id == "5a0454b3-4725-4fce-adb2-f04109a03699")
                                   ).first()

        print(client_list.dict)
        print(client_list.json())
        print(client_list.jobs)

    return client_list


app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(router)

# For CORS support, the allowed origins
origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:3000/",
    "http://localhost:8000",
]
# CORS options
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["X-Total-Count"],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="localhost", port=8000, log_level="info", reload=True)
```

First, if I try to use my code with the `@router.get("/", response_model=List[ClientsRead])`, I get an error:

```
File "/home/diego/python/financeiro/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 291, in app content = await serialize_response(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/diego/python/financeiro/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 154, in serialize_response
    raise ResponseValidationError(
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError)
```

I don't have any idea what is the field or problem with my schemas, I tried to follow the way the tutorial show, but I think I missed something because of this error.

If I try `@router.get("/")` (without response_model) my response in the `/docs` not show the related fields notes or jobs, (and I had records related, I see using sqlite browser) the other fields are fine.

In my `print(client_list.dict)` or `print(client_list.jobs)` I can see the related jobs for example. But in my `print(client_list.json())`, the jobs field do not appears.

What I'm doing wrong? Why my response_model does not work and why I can't see the related data in my response/json?
I tried to found solutions, but I couldn't find a really similar issue, and I tried some things I found, but without success...

Another question (less important, is a doubt) I was using Tortoise ORM and now I'm trying to migrate to SQLModel and I was using the filters as above, they came as parameters in my url from my front end and I was using a dict and strings to make the filters. It is possible to do something this way with SQLModels? I can filter using strings? O another way to filter using the query parameters that are not None or that appears in my request?

#### Final summary of what I expected:

My json response with the related data nested in it.

And I would want to know how to use filters as a dictionary (in a similar way I was doing before with TortoiseORM)

My best regards, Diego.